# Ambiguous Reference To Member 'Subscript' when using UIApplicationShortcutItem

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, 3dtouch

I am trying to migrate my code to Swift 3, and came across an error regarding trying to handle 3D Touch shortcuts..

I get the following error

> Performing segue using 3D Touch Shortcut - Ambiguous Reference To
>   Member 'Subscript'

For the following line

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: Any]?) -> Bool {

if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
}


}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this, does anyone else know ?

Here's how I am handling the shortcuts

```
enum ShortcutItemType: String {
case First
case Second
case Third

init?(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) {
    guard let last = shortcutItem.type.components(separatedBy: ".").last else { return nil }
    self.init(rawValue: last)
}

var type: String {
    return Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
}
}


fileprivate func handleShortcutItem(_ shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) {

    if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController, let shortcutItemType = ShortcutItemType(shortcutItem: shortcutItem) {

     let rootNavController = rootViewController.childViewControllers.first as! UINavigationController

        let viewController = rootNavController.childViewControllers[1]

        switch shortcutItemType {
        case .First:
            viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstSegue", sender: self)
            break
        case .Second:
            viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
            break
        case .Third:

            //Segue to view controller from first then perform another segue to a modal view. 

            viewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "thirdSegue", sender: self)
            break
        }
    }
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
}
```

Comment: But what is `launchOptions`? Your code refers to it but you give no clue as to where it comes from or what type it is.

Comment: @matt sorry It was from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` see updated answer

Comment: That's the problem right there. Your signature for `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method header of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` has changed to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil)
```

The symbol `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey` has been replaced with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem`.

And this may be another issue, but `application(_:performActionFor:completionHandler:)` needs to have this header:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

Try fixing all of them.